# How can I extend a TypeScript interface and infer the arguments?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface.

```
interface Actions {
  onSearchByAddress: (s: State, p: string) => State
  onSetSalesType: (s: State, p: string[]) => State
}
```

I want to generate another interface (or type) with the same function names, but with a different function signature.

The function signature should accept the second argument as the first and return `void`.

```
interface ConnectedActions {
  onSearchByAddress: (p: string) => void
  onSetSalesType: (p: string[]) => void
}
```

At the moment I'm stuck here

```
type ConnectedActions = {
  [P in keyof Actions]: Actions[P]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use a [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) inside your mapped type to [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) the second parameter of each function property, like this:

```
type ConnectedActions = {
  [P in keyof Actions]: (
    Actions[P] extends (s: State, y: infer Y) => State ? (p: Y) => void : never
  )
}
```

That type is equivalent to

```
type ConnectedActions = {
    onSearchByAddress: (p: string) => void;
    onSetSalesType: (p: string[]) => void;
}
```

which is what you're looking for.  Hope that helps; good luck.